# Bugsense - Transmitting ping timed out

Tags: android, bugsense

BugSense throws a little exception for me. It works (every time!?) and I still get email notifications when my app crashes in my hand. I want to know just in case, what is this error message?

Does anybody know?

Exception:

```
 W/BugSenseHandler(2881): Transmitting ping Exception Connect to /168.63.83.24:443 timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the app can't connect to the IP 168.63.83.24 on port **443** (which is usually for **HTTPS**), it `times out` before it's able to connect.

Comment: Could it be a problem with sending reports to my email? Could it be that i didnt get all of the error reports because of this ?

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so, that error clearly states it couldn't connect to the specific IP on the specified port, within the specified time out limit. But that isn't an Exception, it's a Warning, you might have other errors?

Comment: No, i only got this. Well, i stop further investigation, it shouldnt be a problem at all.